# How to handle data value inside Optional type of List data

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, option-type

I want to simplify my code without using too many If-Else condition.
The business logic I want is:

- I retrieved data of customer's account from DB
- I want to check whether each customer is qualified for applying new product
- If She/He has the account, then passed
- Otherwise failed.

Repository

```java
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, String>{   
    Optional<List<Account>> findAcctByCustoNo(String custNo);
}
```

The logic code

```java
Optional<List<Account>> accounts = myRepo.findAcctByCustoNo(auth.getCustNo());
        if(!accounts.isPresent()) {
            return "invalid param";
        }

        accounts.ifPresent(list->list.stream()
                                     .filter(type -> type.getAccCd().equals("typeA") || type.getAccCd().equals("typeB"))
                                     .forEach(System.out::println));
```

The code hasn't finished yet. I need to check, after filtering the data, if it still return null value, I want to return "No Data" message, something like this. Or apply another method or else.
And I don't know how to do it properly. Because What I can think is add create new instance after filtering, and check it with isPresent again. But I have a feeling that I can do it inside the `accounts` instance.
Please enlighten me.

I just use this Optional feature recently. I spent a lot of time understanding the method inside it. I was thinking to utilize map, but again, I have no idea how to implement it in the right way.

Comment: Returning a string of `"invalid param"` seems like a mistake. Your app is [stringly typed](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/31876/stringly-typed). Throw an exception or something.

Comment: I just spent time formatting your code and you have wrecked it again with your edit. Please fix it....

Comment: @Michael i saw your revision, and I edited the revision version. I don't understand why your revision is gone. And please ignore the return type, actually because this code is inside a method that return String. So I return string

Comment: you can use  Optional.orElse()  method in the end of you statement and return "No Data" in it

Comment: @VladCheremisin where should I put this orElse()? I have tried to add this after ifPresent, and .forEach. but this method is not detected. I need to create it in separate line

Comment: offtopic: You could consider to return an empty List in `findAcctByCustoNo` in case there is no results. That is what would make sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how you intend to use the info after, but if you just need to see if the customer qualifies, you can try

```
boolean qualify = accounts.stream()
                .filter(type -> type.getAccCd().equals("typeA") || type.getAccCd().equals("typeB"))
                .findFirst()
                .isPresent();
```

This will return true if the customer qualifies, otherwise false.

Answer (score 1):

What about this ?
Do all the filtering you want, then use findAny (cheaper than count() since it will stop as soon as it has a match) and check the result

```
Optional<List<Account>> accounts = myRepo.findAcctByCustoNo(auth.getCustNo());

return accounts //
  .map(List::stream) //
  .orElseGet(Stream::empty) //
  .filter(type -> type.getAccCd().equals("typeA") || type.getAccCd().equals("typeB")) //
  .findAny() //
  .orElse(null)
  != null;
```

Explanation

map your optional List to a stream

if not, use an empty stream

then, filter all you want

findAny ? we are good.

orElse, return null

And finally, check for null.

Test code on simpler data :

```
@Test
public void test_checkArray() {

    Assert.assertFalse(this.checkArray(null));
    Assert.assertFalse(this.checkArray(Arrays.asList()));
    Assert.assertFalse(this.checkArray(Arrays.asList("not a!", "b", "c")));
    Assert.assertTrue(this.checkArray(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c")));
}

private boolean checkArray(final List<String> a) {

    return Optional //
        .ofNullable(a) //
        .map(List::stream) //
        .orElseGet(Stream::empty) //
        .filter(aa -> "a".equals(aa)) //
        .findAny() //
        .orElse(null)
        != null;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. it was very helpful. I got an idea after seeing this code!

Comment: Glad to help. A thumb up would have been nice too ;)

Comment: I'd like to, but unfortunately my thumb is not recorded and displayed :(

Answer (score 0):

You can rearrange code like this

```
Optional.of(myRepo.findAcctByCustoNo(auth.getCustNo()))
.filter(.....)
.orElse(......);
```

Optional methods return Optional object, thus it allows method chaining.